# sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: unix, jenkins, sed, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have my docker images upload in the nexus. I need to pull and replace the latest image to the Ansible playbook.

[image: Screenshot of Nexus Docker Registry]

Below is my code and ansible file

```
def dockerTag(){
    env.Docker_tag = sh (script: "git rev-parse --short HEAD | tr -d '\n'", returnStdout: true)
}

pipeline{
    agent any

    stages{
        stage('Git checkout'){
            steps { 
                git 'https://github.com/xxxxx/'
            }
        }    
        
        stage('Maven Build'){
         steps {
 withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'mvn-credentials', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
 sh "/opt/maven/bin/mvn -s /opt/maven/conf/settings.xml package  -Dproject.username=${USERNAME} -Dproject.password=${PASSWORD}"
      }
    }
 }
    
stage('Build Docker Image'){
  steps{
      dockerTag()
  sh "docker build . -t 10.220.110.10:8083/halosys:${dockerTag()}"
  }
}    

stage('Push Docker Image to Nexus'){
  steps{
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'pwd', variable: 'nexus3')]) {
    sh "docker login -u admin -p ${nexus3} 10.220.110.10:8083"
    sh "docker push 10.220.110.10:8083/halosys:${dockerTag()}"
      } 
    }
 }    

   
   stage('Running Ansible playbook'){
     steps{
         dockerTag()
         
         sh '''
            echo $Docker_tag
            sed -i "s/docker_tag/$Docker_tag/g" nexus-image-pull.yml
           ''' 
     
     }  
       
   }
   
   

   }
}
```

```
nexus-image-pull.yml Playbook code
---
- hosts: webservers
  become: True
  tasks:
    - name: pull an image
      docker_image:
      name: 10.220.110.10:8083/halosys:docker_tag
      source: pull
...
```

**When i am trying to fetch the latest images from Nexus and substituting the value to yml file. I am getting error like**

```
sed -i 's/docker_tag/01255bc
/g' nexus-image-pull.yml
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

Please help to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it like this: `sed -e \'s!docker_tag!\'"$Docker_tag"\'!g\'`

Here I am using `!` as separator in `sed` and `\` is used to escape `'`

In bash, the command would be like: `sed -e 's!docker_tag!'"$Docker_tag"'!g'` but since you're using : *sh **'''** <somecode_here> **'''***, in which `'` is used already, we have to escape `'` in sed

---

### **Update:**

I suspected when you wrote: **sed -i 's/docker_tag/01255bc /g' nexus-image-pull.yml sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command** about the space coming between 01255bc and /.

It must have been like below in console log of pipeline:

```
sed -i 's/docker_tag/01255bc 
/g' nexus-image-pull.yml 
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command
```

Therefore, I tried to run your pipeline and I think the issue that you're facing is due to *newline char* `\n` at the end of git commit id.

However, I modified the script according to a working script that I created for something else and it's running for me. My version of your Script:

```
def dockerTag(){
    env.Docker_tag = sh (script: "git rev-parse --short HEAD | tr -d '\n'", returnStdout: true)
}

pipeline{
    agent any

stages {

 stage('Running Ansible playbook'){
     steps{
         dockerTag()
         
         sh '''
           echo $Docker_tag
   
          sed -i "s/docker_tag/$Docker_tag/g" nexus-image-pull.yml
          '''
         
     }  
       
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: I have updated your code like sh '''sed -ie \'s!docker_tag!\'"$Docker_tag"\'!g\''' nexus-image-pull.yml'   Still i am getting same error like sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Try to run `cat nexus-image-pull.yml | sed -e "s/docker_tag/$Docker_tag/g"` and see if it runs.

This will just output the modified file and won't alter Original file

Comment: Even ```cat nexus-image-pull.yml | sed -e "s/docker_tag/$Docker_tag/g"``` giving me same error

Comment: I just updated my answer and shared a working script there. Maybe give it a try?

Comment: Excellent catch yes there is \n at the end of commit id. I have update your code BUILD success but ```sed -i s/docker_tag/null/g nexus-image-pull.yml``` instead of commid id it is storing as value null. Please help me to fix this issue

Comment: I have pasted my code with your updates on the top. Please look into it

Comment: You don't need to call dockerTag() everywhere, just call it once in git code checkout stage and use $Docker_tag everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You may have introduced a backtick instead of an apostrophe: There are two different marks in this line (unterminated `s') which suggests this might be an easy fix.

> sed -ir 's/docker_tag/01255bc /g' nexus-image-pull.yml sed: -e
> expression #1, char 20: unterminated `s' command